# History of queries in MySql

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to check the query that occurs in my MySql database?

For example:
I have an application (OTRS) that allows you to generate reports according to the frames that I desire. I would like to know which query is made by the application in the database.

Because I will use it to integrate with other reporting software.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html (just don't leave it on in production, it'll fill up fast)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enable logging in your MySQL server. there are several types of logs you can use, depending on what you want to log, starting from errors only or slow queries, and to logs that write everything done on your server.

See the full doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although, as Nir says, mysql can log all queries (you should be looking at the general log or the slow log configured with a threshold of 0 seconds) this will show all the queries being run; on a production system it may prove difficult to match what you are doing in your browser with specific entries in the log.

The reason I suggest using the slow query log is that there are tools available which will remove the parameters from the queries, allowing you to see what SQL code is running more frequently.

If you have some proficiency in Perl it should be straightforward to output - all queries are processed [via an abstraction layer](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/developer/stable/en/html/ch02s02.html).

(Presumably you are aware that the [schema is published](http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/doc/database-schema/))